# Android: How can I make merging vertically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I would like to make an Android application. This app requires 7 rows and 7 columns like 7*7 matrix. Here are the questions:

1) How can I merge the cell 1*1 with 2*1 or 1*1,2*1 and 3*1 vertically? 
2) Also Can I make this dynamically? 
3) Which layout should I use?

Thank you in advance.

here is screen.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="8"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="9" >


<Space
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="0" 
    android:tag=""/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Monday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Monday"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Monday"
    />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Tuesday"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Tuesday"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Wednesd."
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Wednesday"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Thursday"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Thursday"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Friday"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Friday"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Saturday"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    android:tag="Saturday"/>

<Space
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="0" 
    android:tag=""/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="8:00"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="8:30"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="9:00"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:text="9:30"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:text="10:00"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:text="10:30"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:text="11:00"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="8"
    android:text="11:30"
    android:textSize="10dp" 
    />
```

here is mainActivity

```
public class Example extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen);

    Button lec = new Button(this);
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(1, 3);
    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1, 7);



    gridLayout.addView(lec, params);

}
```

I am doing a program for machine, columns represents the days of working of that machine and rows represent how many hours work that machine. Because of this, I have to stretch out a button from the starting hour to the ending hour but I can't achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried something already ? Post your code :)

Comment: You should use table layout and merge their cells as you want

Comment: @Prag's `TableLayout` does not work here. A `TableLayout` only supports column spans, no row spans, so you couldn't merge cells vertically as the OP wants to. But a `GridLayout` supports both row and column spans, see my answer for more information.

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `GridLayout`! It works like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

    ...

</GridLayout>
```

To define how many rows and columns there are use these two attributes on the GridLayout:

- `android:columnCount`
- `android:rowCount`

You can define the position of a View inside the GridLayout with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_column`
- `android:layout_row`

And you can define how many rows or columns a View spans with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_rowSpan`
- `android:layout_columnSpan`

Please note that the GridLayout was only added with API level 14! If you want to use the GridLayout in earlier versions you need to use the GridLayout from the support library:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...    

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

---

You can also populate a `GridLayout` programmatically with its `LayoutParams` like this:

```
final int row = 1;  // View starts in second row
final int rowSpan = 2; // View spans two rows

final int column = 1; // View starts in second column
final int columnSpan = 2; // View spans two columns

// Creating the LayoutParams from the values above
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column, columnSpan);
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, rowSpan);

// Adding the new View with the LayoutParams
gridLayout.addView(view, params);
```

I suggest you add a helper method to simplify this:

```
private void addViewToGridLayout(View view, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan) {
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column, columnSpan);
    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, rowSpan);

    gridLayout.addView(view, params);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add wievs dynamically to GridLayout from source code? Like this: lets assume variable a is a GridLayout a.addView(Button b);a.setColumn(4);a.setRow(2).

Comment: Sure, you can define all the xml values I talked about above using `LayoutParams` just like in a `RelativeLayout`. If you give me a few minutes I can edit an example into my answer.

Comment: firstly,thnks to you for your answer..but there is one problem.I think this is my fault but I can not find it.I can not stretch out button throughout the cell which spanned.I mean button did not fill 3 cell

Comment: The positions are a 0 based index, but spans are not, so if you have 8 columns and want the `View` to span all of them you need a columnSpan of 8, not 7.

Comment: let's assume there is a machine this works on Monday from 8 o'clock to 11 o'clock so I have to add a button and this should fill 3cell I dont want to span all of them..

Comment: Oh now I get it, so `GridLayout.spec(1, 3)` makes the `View` span only two columns or what? I doubt that. But if the problem is more extensive you should ask a new question.